# opencpu cloud server installation guide on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, opencpu

Would anyone know or like to share their note on installing opencpu cloud server on ubuntu 16.04?

I thought it is easy, but we saw many error here and there when following the instructions. I am new to opencpu. And, I don't have much experience on apache and nignx.

Here is the long story:

I created a new and clean ubuntu 16.04 server from microsoft azure vm, and installed opencpu cloud server following:

```
# Requires Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) or 16.04 (Xenial)
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:opencpu/opencpu-1.6
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade

# Installs OpenCPU server
sudo apt-get install -y opencpu
```

The server reported insserv error when running opencpu init script

```
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header dpkg
```

We then did some goolge and fix around, we got apache2 running, but when called:

```
curl http://localhost/ocpu/info
```

received 404 error.

FYI, the single user server runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we found is that opencpu need mod_R to be turned on from apache2:

```
sudo a2enmod R
```

You need first to change to dir:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available
```

And, make sure R.load file exists.

After running a2enmod command, should see a link to R.load (R module) in

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you y g for your question and response .. I had the same problem i try what you have mentioned in your comment but

> curl http://localhost/cpu/info

takes along time without no response.

Thank you.

Comment: You might need to specify a port, such as ```curl http://localhost: 8004/cpu/info```?

Answer (score 0):

I used **opencpu 1.5** works without bugs on ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:opencpu/opencpu-1.5 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install R and then install opencpu

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
sudo apt-get install -y opencpu
```

Also you should probably install Rstudio for IDE access

```
sudo apt-get install rstudio-server
```

To login to R you'll need to make a new user - follow the prompts

```
sudo adduser myname
```

Now just to make sure its all working

```
sudo service opencpu restart
sudo service rstudio-server restart
```

And try something like to check if its working

```
curl -L -v localhost/ocpu/library/
```

which should return a list of packages now installed on Ubuntu like this

[Final Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om09o.png)